# Jackson - Mapping an Object type field of json representation of class1 to class2

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I have two POJOs defined :

Class1 -

```
public class Class1 {

        Map<String, Object> param1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        Map<String, Object> param2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        Object body;

        // getters-setters...
}
```

Class2 -

```
public class Class2   {

  private String name = null;
  private String description = null;
  private List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<Integer>();

  // getters-setters...
  }
```

The body field is dynamic so I have made it an Object type. I generate the Class2 Pojo at run time using `swagger codegen`. So basically `body` object represents the Class2. Class1 is the fixed class and al the fields are known.

```
json -
{
  "param1" : {
    "id" : 132
  },
  "param2" : {
    "address" : "String"
  },

  "body" : {
    "name" : "value",
    "description" : "value",
    "data" : [ ]
  }
}
```

I can deserialize above json for Class1 :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Class1 ij = mapper.readValue(new File(path_of_above_json), Class1.class);
param1 = ij.getParam1();
param2 = ij.getParam2();
Object body = ij.getBody();
```

I want to map the body field to Class2. I can do the same with gson :

```
Class2 body1 = new Class2();
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Class2.class, new ResponseBodyDeserializer<Class2>()).create();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
InputStream in = MainClass.class.getResourceAsStream(path_of_above_json);
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
body1 = gson.fromJson(r , Class2.class);
```

with additional class ResponseBodyDeserializer -

```
class ResponseBodyDeserializer<T> implements JsonDeserializer<T>
{
    @Override
    public T deserialize(JsonElement je, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jdc)
        throws JsonParseException
    {
        // Get the element from the parsed JSON
        JsonElement content = je.getAsJsonObject().get("body");

        // Deserialize it
        return new Gson().fromJson(content, type);
    }
}
```

Can we achieve the same thing with Jackson so as to avoid this additional class?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static class Class1<T> {
    private Map<String, Object> param1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    private Map<String, Object> param2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    private T body;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Class1<Class2> ij =  mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Class1<Class2>>() {});
Map<String, Object> param1 = ij.getParam1();
Map<String, Object> param2 = ij.getParam2();
Class2 body = ij.getBody();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the modified version of your code,

```
    public class Class1<T> {

            Map<String, Object> param1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            Map<String, Object> param2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            T body;

            // getters-setters...
    }

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Class1 ij = mapper.readValue(new File(path_of_above_json), Class1<Class2>.class);
    param1 = ij.getParam1();
    param2 = ij.getParam2();

Class2 body1 = ij.getBody();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I can't pass Class1<Class2>.class as argument. Gives error `Class1 can not be resolves to a variable`